# How to Sort an Array of Numbers of String Datatype without using Inbuilt sort() and atoi method in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am trying sort the below given Array without converting the strings to number(without atoi function) and also without using sort() inbuilt function

inputArr = ["1","2","10","3","21","15"]

```
let len = inputArr.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < len; j++) {
            if (inputArr[j] > inputArr[j + 1]) {
                let tmp = inputArr[j];
                inputArr[j] = inputArr[j + 1];
                inputArr[j + 1] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
    return inputArr;
```

But the above code doesn't sort the numbers in correct order

Output Expected: ["1","2","3",,"10","15","21"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be approaching the problem by using a BubbleSort, so tried to come up with a solution using the same algorithm.

The **issue** is with your comparison.

You will see that

```
"1" < "10" === true
```

But

```
"2" < "10" === false
```

So you need to check each character of the string to determine whether the number is actually smaller or not.
Here is the code:

```
    const arr = ["1", "2", "10", "3", "21", "15"];
    const len = arr.length;

    const isGreater = (num1, num2) => {
        if (num1.length < num2.length) return false;
        for (let i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
           if(num1[i] === num2[i]) continue;
           return (num1[i] > num2[i]);
        }
        return false;
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        for (let j = 0; j < len - i - 1; ++j) {
            if (arr[j].length > arr[j + 1].length || isGreater(arr[j], arr[j + 1])) {
                let tmp = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
                arr[j + 1] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }

    console.log(arr);
```

The function isGreater will do that check for you.

Answer (score 0):

```js
inputArr = ["1","2","10","3","21","15"]

const sorted = inputArr.sort((a, b) => Number(a) - Number(b))
console.log(sorted);
```

Comment: Yes, it will sort in order when we use sort() method. But how do i sort it without using an inbuilt function and also without converting the string element to integer

Comment: It's not converting it. It's only converting the values for comparison. The result will still be strings. Why would you want to implement your own sorting function? Is this homework?

Comment: This isn't homework. I am working out for solutions without using any in-built methods in js. I want to sort with any of sorting algorithms

Comment: So, this is more of a algorithm question rather than a JS question.

Comment: The answer from @adiutor-robattus looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const a = ["1","2","3",,"10","15","21"];
a.sort((x, y) => x-y);
```